# Extjs4 how to hide tool tip

Tags: extjs4

I have a chart with tool tip. What i want is when i move the mouse over certain data the tooltip should hide and if i move it on someother data it should display again. My sample code is:

```
            tips = {
        trackMouse : true,
        width : 120,
        height : 26,
        renderer : function(storeItem, item){
            if(item.yField == 'temp'){
            this.hide();    
            } else{
            this.setTitle(storeItem.get(xFld)+':'+item.value[1]);
            }
        };
```

I tried `hide();`, `destroy();`, `disable();` and `visibility();` but nothing worked.
Can anyone give me the proper solution for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the ToolTip's [beforeShow](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip-event-beforeshow) event.  Return `true` if you want the ToolTip to show, `false` otherwise.

```
beforeShow: function(item) {
    return item.yField !== 'temp';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the ToolTip's beforeShow event
Return true if you want the ToolTip to show, false otherwise.
It worked for me and it saved my time . thanks Kevin